# How to save a file using a variable in the name?

Tags: matlab

This is my name now:

```
  fn_la= ' myfile.env'
```

In this name I want to include a variable called `date= 20170805.`
So the name is `myfile20170805.env.`
Some one know how to do that in matlab?

Comment: Assuming `date` is a string, `fn_la = ['myfile' date '.env']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
fn_la= ' myfile.env'
date= 20170805
C = strsplit(fn_la,'.')
name=sprintf('%s%d.%s.',C{1},date,C{2})
```

You might want to use `strtrim` to remove the whitespace:

```
name=strtrim(name)
```

Comment: When dealing with file names/paths, a safer alternative to `strsplit` might be to use [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html), such as: `[filePath, fileName, fileExt] = fileparts(fn_la); fullPath = fullfile(filePath, sprintf('%s%d%s', fileName, date, fileExt));`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Glad I helped! @gnovice using fileparts it is indeed a very good way!